# interpret sns.pairplot image for outlier

Tags: dataframe, data-science, scatter-plot

An online notebook uses sns.pairplot to create the image below. The author of the notebook then infer from this image that the data seems to suffer from outliers.

Can someone please explain to me how such inference was made? is it from the few points that are far away from the other points?

[image]

Comment: Without the full context of the notebook I would agree that the outliers are the points that are far away from the main clusters.

Comment: I think you should drop the outcome feature. It adds no value, or insight, to your analysis.